# Loop Through a String and Replace Full Stops with a New Line in Kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I have some cooking instructions obtained as an API response but it is in prose (sample below). I need to format and put a new line for every full stop`(.)` in the sentense.

> "Put the flour, eggs, milk, 1 tbsp oil and a pinch of salt into a bowl or large jug, then whisk to a smooth batter. Set aside for 30 mins to rest if you have time, or start cooking straight away.\r\nSet a medium frying pan or crêpe pan over a medium heat and carefully wipe it with some oiled kitchen paper. When hot, cook your pancakes for 1 min on each side until golden, keeping them warm in a low oven as you go.\r\nServe with lemon wedges and sugar, or your favourite filling.

I am working with the below code but it is not putting the new line/ line break after the full stop.

```
val input = meal.directions
val formattedDirections = input.replace("\\.\\s?", "\\.\n")
```

I have looked around similar questions posted for Python, Java, JavaScript, PHP and C++ but I can't find a way out.

Anyone with the Algorithm/Regex or a lead please help

Comment: You want replaceAll, not replace.  Replace isn't a regex.  ReplaceAll is

Comment: @GabeSechan I noted Kotlin doesn't have `replaceAll()` method. I just tried it but IDE can't resolve `replaceAll()` at all.

Comment: In kotlin the version of replace that does regex takes a Regex argument as the first parameter, not a string.  fun CharSequence.replace(
    regex: Regex,
    replacement: String
): String

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan for the clarification, it is clear now I needed to use the Regex.

Comment: .replace(".\\r\\n", ".\n"). And this leaves the dot as you wanna keep it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace` method itself replaces all occurrences and not just one occurrence.

But if you specify a string literal as first argument, it only literally replaces that string even if it contains a regex.

To treat first argument as a regex, you need to convert it to a regex object by either calling `.toRegex()` method on string literal or by creating an object of `Regex`. Sample code following,

```
val formattedDirections = input.replace("\\.\\s?".toRegex(), "\\.\n")
```

OR

```
val formattedDirections = input.replace(Regex("\\.\\s?"), "\\.\n")
```

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh for your input, I replaced the String Literal with the Regex and it now works!